# Adding Images to autocomplete suggestions

Tags: php, html, image-processing, autocomplete

I have a search box that when you write in it gives you some suggestions from an existing mysql database.. So when you hit enter after picking one of the suggestions it copies the whole name and puts it into the search box.. **The problem is** that when I tried to add the corresponding image to each of the suggestions.. it shows it but when the user picks one it copies the whole code in the search box. This is what I get in the search box when I pick one of the suggestions

```
<img id='sugImg' src='./images_store/"11258.jpg' height='25' width='25' style='vertical-align:middle;'/> element_name
```

Here's my code..

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT NAME,PRID from PRODUCT WHERE PID='$PID' AND BID='$BID' AND  NAME LIKE '%$q%'");
while($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $cname = $rs['NAME'];
        $PRID= $rs['PRID'];
        echo "<img src='./images_store/".$PID."".$BID."".$PRID.".jpg' height='25' width='25' style='vertical-align:middle;'/> $cname\n";
}
```

Is there a way to separate the Image from the element_name??

Answer (score 0):

I assume that each search suggestion is wrapped inside a div or whatever like this...

```
<div class='element'>
  <img id='sugImg' src='./images_store/"11258.jpg' height='25' width='25' style='vertical-align:middle;'/> element_name
</div>
```

And then when you are in the process of selecting the option you'll do something like this:

```
function selectElement() {
   var element_name=$('.element').html();
   //do stuff with element_name
}
```

So if all of the above is true (and if it's not, can you show the javascript code where you're selecting the element?), then all you would need to do is change it to...

```
function selectElement() {
   var element_name=$('.element').text();
   //do stuff with element_name
}
```

...to make it so only the text of what's inside the DIV is being used, not the full html.